# $M_{m×n}$ and $M_{n×m}$ are isomorphic?

Tags: linear-algebra

$M_{m×n}$ and $M_{n×m}$ are isomorphic?

I know if I want to show isomorphism
I have to find a linear transformation $T$ first, and then check it is invertible.
In here, I have no idea how to set up that $T$.

Answer (score 4):

what about $T \colon M_{n,m} \to M_{m,n}$, defined as $T(A) = A^t$?
It is also really easy to find an inverse: $T(T(A)) = (A^t)^t = A$, therefore $T = T^{-1}$.

Comment: Transposition is not a homomorphism. $T(AB) \not= T(A)T(B)$. If T(A) and T(B) were to commute, then this would work, but in general they do not.

Comment: Transposition is a ring *antihomomorphism* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antihomomorphism So the two rings are isomorphic one to the opposite of the other.

Comment: It depends on the kind of isomorphism you want to show. It's clearly an isomorphism as vector spaces. And it's obviously an isomorphism of algebras once you pass to an opposite algebra. ($(M_{n,m})^{op} \cong M_{m,n}$.)

Comment: The tag is linear-algebra so I supposed we were thinking the two spaces as vector spaces.

Comment: If $n\ne m$ it makes no sense anyway to postulate any additional structure beyond vector space over the ground field (or module over the groud ring?)